# Losing ASP session variables, or so I think

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a relatively simple ASP.Net application that I have built some simplistic security into. The user logs in with a username and password and I check it against the DB. If it is successful I store a User object for them on a session variable called "UserID" and redirect them to the same page, only this time they dont see the login panel. (Mmm could just hide it dynamically but I think that would cause a page reload anyway)

On my Default.aspx page I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        LoginPanel.Visible = true;
    }
}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Security security = new Security();
    Session["UserID"] = security.LoginUser(txtUsername.Text, txt2Password.Value);
    if (Session["UserID"] != null)
    {                
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Right, so far so good. Also worth mentioning at this point is the master page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        //Check that we are not already on the default.aspx page.
        //Don't want to cause infinite redirect here
        if (!Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("default.aspx"))
        {
            Page.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Otherwise we get the UserObject from the session and display menu items           //based on the role. Nothing fancy.

    }


}

//Bad naming. This a logout link on the master...
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Session["UserID"] = null;
    Page.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Now all of this works perfectly on my local instance of IIS. As soon as I deploy this to our production server and I click on one of my menu items and navigate say to Search.aspx it chucks me back to my Default.aspx page with the LoginPanel visible??? Also that is in Firefox. With IE I can click on the Search.aspx menu link and it takes me to the page, but clicking on an edit link in my GridView also chucks me back to the Default.aspx page with the LoginPanel showing.

I'm no ASP.net expert at all and I'm at wits end. So please word Answers with as little as possible jargon and so forth and post links to msdn for docs and such so that I don't just resolve this, but actually understand why this has been giving me nightmares.

TIA

Comment: Is your production server in a web farm?

Comment: Have you moved the database up to the server?  Does it have the same information as your local copy?

Comment: Not sure if the server is in a farm. Database was moved up without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store user identifiers or other sensitive information in the session, implement `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` with `Forms` authentication instead (though this doesn't completely rule out information exposure altogether).

This enables easy access to certain elements in the nature of what you need:

```
//to sign-in:
FormsAuthentication.SignIn("username", createPersistentLogin);

//to sign-out:
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

//user data access:
Page.User.IsInRole("requiredRole");

Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

Page.User.Name;
```

A couple of snippets from MSDN to explain the meaning of this:

> The .NET Framework provides a
>   role-based security implementation in
>   the System.Security.Principal
>   namespace, which you can use for
>   authorizing and authenticating users
>   in your application.

---

> An IIdentity encapsulates an
>   authenticated user. An IPrincipal is a
>   combination of the identity of the
>   user and any roles he or she has. You
>   can use the predefined identity and
>   principal classes in the
>   System.Security.Principal namespace or
>   you can add custom authentication by
>   creating classes that implement the
>   interfaces.

---

> Care should be used when granting
>   permissions to work with IIdentity
>   objects, because these objects make
>   sensitive user-related information
>   available. You should protect the
>   application's current IPrincipal
>   object from changes because the
>   application's authorization capability
>   is based on its current principal.

You can get information on doing this [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172765%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

maybe a bit off topic but I would recommend to use built in login functionality, that means Login Controls, Membership and Authentication. Then you don't have to mess with Session

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

then you can do Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey for example to get the key

Comment: Mmm yeah, maybe I should've done this from the start. I've never used this before. Could you give me some pointers how I would use this? Not using windows authentication, just using a tables in the db called users, roles and a bridge table br_userroles

Comment: you don't have to use windows auth., you should use forms auth. and of course you can have your own tables, you need to implement custom Membership Provider and set it in web.config, here is how to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx the same is for RoleProvider. The communication with DB happens inside those providers, you just have to override the methods

Comment: @Robert: `Forms Authentication` != `ASP.NET Membership`.

Comment: Difficult to decide who to give this to. Both Robert and Mr Disappointment were a big help with resolving the issue, but not giving me any insight into the original problem at hand. I've implemented the Forms Authentication now and waiting for our website admin to deploy the site to production so I can see whats potting and if the session issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if in your production server the Web.Config file of your site contains this line, or something like this :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

It must be inside  element.

It is to verify wich sessionState are you using.

See the link : 
[Asp.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)